# Return an object of a TypeClass fails with "rigid type variable"

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell by implementing some [ProjectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/) problems.
I want to set up a generic Problem infrastructure so that I can call a problem by number.

I therefore create the following types:

The `EulerProblem` Type Class defines some methods a Problem must provide:

```hs
class EulerProblem a where
  -- takes a Problem, an Input data string (if any) and returns the solution
  solution :: a -> String -> String
  -- reads Input data from a file, returning an IO String with the file's content
  readInput :: a -> IO String
  readInput x = return ""
```

I create a Type per Problem, and implement the TypeClass for each Problem:

```hs
data Problem1 = Problem1
instance EulerProblem Problem1 where
  solution :: Problem1 -> String -> String
  solution p input = solution
    where
      solution = show "calc some solution 1"

data Problem2 = Problem2
instance EulerProblem Problem2 where
  solution :: Problem2 -> String -> String
  solution p input = solution
    where
      solution = show "calc some solution 2"
```

Then there is a function that gets an EulerProblem instance from a number
(which is entered as a command line param):

```hs
getProblemByNr :: EulerProblem a => Int -> a
getProblemByNr 1 = Problem1
getProblemByNr 2 = Problem2
```

... which I then can call like this:

```hs
s = solution (getProblemByNr 1) "someInputData"
```

But this does not work: Haskell wants a specific type: The definition of
`getProblemByNr` does not compile with the error:

```hs
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Problem1’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      getProblemByNr :: forall a. EulerProblem a => Int -> a
```

I really don't get it: getProblemByNr returns an object of the TypeClass EulerProblem - and
the `solution` function is implemented on each instance - so what's the problem here?
And how can I achieve what I want "the haskell way"?

Comment: You can not use `EulerProblem a => Int -> a`, types are solved at compile time. So at compile type, Haskell needs to fill in a type for `a`. You thus can not "unite" different types of results.

Comment: `getProblemByNr :: EulerProblem a => Int -> a` means that the function must return any `a` that the _caller_ chooses, not that it can choose any `a` itself. It's a fairly common misconception: universal vs. existential quantification. Maybe this is a case where existential types are the right solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have it, there's no point in `EulerProblem` being a class. Classes are for polymorphic stuff that obeys common rules. Your abstraction does not have any of that.

Why not

```
data EulerProblem = EulerProblem
  { solution :: String -> String
  , readInput :: IO String }

problem1 :: EulerProblem
problem1 = EulerProblem
  { solution = \_ -> show "calc some solution 1"
  , readInput = pure "" }

problem2 :: EulerProblem
problem2 = EulerProblem
  { solution = \_ -> show "calc some solution 2"
  , readInput = pure "" }
```

Now you can write

```
getProblemByNr :: Int -> EulerProblem
getProblemByNr 1 = problem1
getProblemByNr 2 = problem2
```

Comment: Seems like I'm just too "biased" from OOP languages :-) I see that type classes work differently than interfaces in OOP languages. But one problem with your proposal persists: What about the IO value readInput here? I cannot just execute an IO action there, I somehow need to initiate that from main - so creating a EulerProblem instance creates an IO action probably (by reading a file content). how can that be achieved in this context?

Comment: Well, they have some overlap. Basically, an OO interface is a specific kind of typeclass plus a data structure that wraps instances of that class into a sharable type. (We call that an _existential_ in Haskell.) But it's seldom a good idea to translate OO code to Haskell this way.

Comment: The `IO` method can be invoked from `main` just like any other IO action.

Comment: The real problem comes from the IO Input: I need the readInput value to compute the solution - this is why I wanted to separate them into own functions in the first place - to allow readInput to be called in main, then pass the resulting String from the IO operation to the solution function. Your proposal sounds legit, but I cannot access readInput to calculate the solution.

Comment: Yes, you _can_ call `readInput` in `main`, the pass the resulting `String` from the `IO` operation to the solution function. Why shouldn't you?

Comment: You're right - I forgot about the lazyness of Haskell - I'll give it a try, and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Actually not lazyness, just monad magic.

Comment: Thanks for your help - that worked indeed. As a newcomer to Haskell I must admit there are some really high hurdles to take - my brain still hurts from thinking backwards :-)

Comment: You're welcome - we the Haskell community are always happy to help newcomers overcome their lack of brain-ache!